# Permissions error creating .bak back-up of SQL Server database on Amazon RDS

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I've inherited a website running on AWS. What I want to do is take a back-up of the SQL Server database (which is on Amazon RDS) so that I can set up a development environment locally. I have log-in credentials for the AWS console but I'm a complete newcomer in this environment so am trying to piece together the processes and terminology.

I've have read the [docs here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/SQLServer.Procedural.Importing.html#SQLServer.Procedural.Importing.Native.Using.Backup) on how to enable import/export of SQL databases. There are 3 set-up steps in this guide:

Firstly, we need an S3 bucket. I see from the console that we already have a bucket called 'sqlbackups', so it would appear the previous dev has already gone through this process.

Secondly we need "An AWS Identity and Access Management (IAM) role to access the bucket". I've checked the console by going to 'IAM' from the 'services' list and selecting 'Roles' from the navigation on the left. We appear to have an IAM role called 'SQL_BackRestore_IAM'. I'm assuming that this is what we need, already set up by the previous dev?

Thirdly, we need "The SQLSERVER_BACKUP_RESTORE option added to an option group on your DB instance.". I've gone to the AWS console > RDS > Option groups and there's a group in there called 'custom-option-group-for-sql-express-v11' which has 'SQLSERVER_BACKUP_RESTORE' as an option. So, again, this looks like it has been set up already.

So now I believe I need to log in to the actual SQL Server and run a command to call a stored procedure to create the .bak backup. So I log into the database using the credentials I have from the website web.config file and I execute this:

```
exec msdb.dbo.rds_backup_database 
@source_db_name='ExampleDBName',
@s3_arn_to_backup_to='arn:aws:s3:::sqlbackups/ExampleDBName.bak',
@type='FULL';
```

However, I now get an error:

`The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'rds_backup_database', database 'msdb', schema 'dbo'`

Presumably it's something to do with the database log-in not having permissions to execute back-ups. I was not given any kind of sa or master database log-in though, so I'm now stuck!

Can anyone suggest how I can get this back-up command to work?

Many thanks.

Comment: You should talk to the DBA who owns the database.  If the database was part of the "inheritance" then you should talk to whomever bequeathed it to you, because having SA access is part of owning a database.

Comment: I don't believe their is a 'sa' role in RDS, or at least it's obfuscated away via the managed part of the service, which is part of my confusion. I've read there's a 'master' role, but again I'm a little confused as to whether that's where I should be looking. I'm hoping someone with good RDA knowledge will know for certain.  It should be possible in the AWS console to reset the master account details so ultimately I do have control, but then I don't know if that's going to break things. I'd rather create a new user with permission to back-up but I've no idea where to start.

Comment: Call it "master", call it "SA", call it "Blue Banana" - whoever owns a database needs to have full and unlimited access to it.  If you don't have the credentials that carry that access then you need to talk to whomever **does** have them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had this same issue.

I solved it by using the RDS master username for login and running the backup procedure.

You can find the master username on the RDS database instance Configuration tab.

So in the AWS console:

RDS, Databases, Select Database, Configuration

If you don't know the master username password, you can also find that by clicking *Modify* on the database instance view. Set the password under Settings.

Comment: Thank you. This should be marked the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

From the docs,

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5042/limitations-of-sql-server-native-backup-and-restore-in-amazon-rds/

The user needs to have Execute permission on the rds_backup_database in the msdb database.

```
USE master 
GO 
CREATE LOGIN rds_backup_operator WITH Password = 'somecomplexpassword', DEFAULT_DATABASE=master, 
   CHECK_EXPIRATION=OFF, CHECK_POLICY=OFF 
GO 

USE msdb 
GO 
CREATE USER rds_backup_operator FROM LOGIN rds_backup_operator 
GO 
GRANT EXECUTE ON msdb.dbo.rds_backup_database TO rds_backup_operator 
GO
```

Hope this helps!!!

Answer (score 0):

I posted an [answer on the AWS Forums](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=986057&#986057) that explains how you can do this in the cleanest way possible, by using Active Directory users/groups and an MSA account to run the backup process.

In the below example, [DOMAIN\msaSqlBackup$] is a managed service account that runs on an EC2 instance and executes the associated backup commands.  [DOMAIN\SQL Admins\ is an AD Group that is a proxy of the [admin] built-in user account provided by AWS SQL Server RDS.  Note the WITH GRANT OPTION [DOMAIN\SQL Admins], which is required to communicate the grant chain from the [admin] user to the [DOMAIN\SQL Admins] AD GROUP to the [DOMAIN\msaSqlBackup$] AD Group MSA account.  Without this step, you need to also execute `GRANT CREATE ANY DATABASE TO [NewLoginName] WITH GRANT OPTION;` and
`GRANT VIEW ANY DATABASE TO [NewLoginName] WITH GRANT OPTION;` *while executing this as the admin account*.  That is not preferred, since it (1) escalates the privileges of the NewLoginName unnecesssarily (2) means you are using a shared password-based account across your DBA team to manage your AWS SQL Server RDS instances.

```
USE master
GO
CREATE LOGIN [DOMAIN\msaSqlBackup$] FROM WINDOWS
GO 
 
USE msdb
GO
CREATE USER [DOMAIN\msaSqlBackup$] FROM LOGIN [DOMAIN\msaSqlbackup$]
GO
GRANT EXECUTE ON msdb.dbo.rds_backup_database TO [DOMAIN\msaSqlBackup$] WITH GRANT OPTION [DOMAIN\SQL Admins]
GO 
GRANT EXECUTE ON msdb.dbo.rds_restore_database TO [DOMAIN\msaSqlBackup$] WITH GRANT OPTION [DOMAIN\SQL Admins]
GO 
GRANT EXECUTE ON msdb.dbo.rds_task_status TO [DOMAIN\msaSqlBackup$] WITH GRANT OPTION [DOMAIN\SQL Admins]
GO 
GRANT EXECUTE ON msdb.dbo.rds_cancel_task TO [DOMAIN\msaSqlBackup$] WITH GRANT OPTION [DOMAIN\SQL Admins]
GO
 
USE name_of_database_to_backup
GO
CREATE USER [DOMAIN\msaSqlBackup$] FROM LOGIN [DOMAIN\msaSqlBackup$]
GO
ALTER ROLE db_backupoperator ADD MEMBER [DOMAIN\msaSqlBackup$]
GO
```